# Trello API authentication not giving a valid user token

Tags: javascript, trello

I'm using the Trello JS client to grab a token for the user. However it keeps giving me back the same token, even if I'm not logged into Trello in that browser.

```
Trello.authorize({
   name: "Task Slayer",
   type: "popup",
   interactive: true,
   expiration: "never",
   success: function () { onTrelloAuthorizeSuccessful(); },
   scope: { write: true, read: true },
});

// Save the token after success call
function onTrelloAuthorizeSuccessful() {
   var token = Trello.token();
   $.get('https://api.trello.com/1/members/me/boards?key=' + TRELLO_CLIENT_KEY + '&token=' + token, {}, function(data){
      console.log(data);
   });
}
```

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: is it possible that the `$.get` is executing before `Trello.authorize` success callback is called? i.e. in your **developer tools console** do you see `Success! token` before or after the `GET https://api.trello.com/` starts? ... oh, and how are `TRELLO_CLIENT_KEY` and `TRELLO_USER_TOKEN` vars set? There's no indication in your code that these are ever declared

Comment: @JaromandaX - Please assume those variables are available. I can see them correctly being included in the AJAX calls in developer tools. And yes the GET function is being called after the authorization success function. It has the correct user key in the ajax call :/

Comment: So you're saying that `TRELLO_USER_TOKEN` gets set to `token`? You've confirmed they are the same?

Comment: Yes I've confirmed TRELLO_USER_TOKEN is being set as the user token returned from the authentication. Authentication always returns the same token. I'll change up those var names to make this clear...

Comment: Have you tried reproducing this with Postman or cURL? I wonder if headers or origin might be screwing it up

Comment: Actually I just noticed that it keeps giving me the same token back even if I'm not logged into Trello. So it seems that it's not actually authenticating, and is giving me a dummy token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that the authorize() method has an argument 'persist' that defaults to true. If it's true, it stores the first token returned in local storage and no longer actually authenticates after that.

So I added `persist: false` and it started working :)

Comment: After opening the popup I am clicking the allow button then the pop is changed to blank page. After that noting is happening.. Each time page is loaded the pop is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Add it in your url:

```
&scope=read,write,account&response_type=token
```

Like: https://trello.com/1/authorize?expiration=never&scope=read,write,account&response_type=token&name=YourAppName&key=YourKey